# Adding data to two tables using a single php form

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySql and phpmyadmin, I have two tables `person` and `report` which are linked using the field `person_id` as a foreign key in the `report` table. Using one php form I am trying to add a persons details to the `person` table. Using the same form I want it to post the date to the `report` table which will then generate an auto increment `report_id` and link that person with a specific report on that date using the `person_id` foreign key.

Here is my current code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('dbcon.php'); //link to connection file

    $pid = "SELECT person_id FROM person\n"
         . "ORDER BY person_id DESC\n"
         . "LIMIT 1"; //variable finds last generated person_id

    $sqlinsert1 = "INSERT INTO person (person.title, person.first_name, person.last_name,  person.address, person.contact_no, person.email, person.ha_id) VALUES ('$_POST[title]' , '$_POST[first_name]' , '$_POST[last_name]' , '$_POST[address]' , '$_POST[contact_no]' , '$_POST[email]' , '$_POST[ha_id]')";

    $sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO report (report.date) VALUES ('$_POST[date]') WHERE ($pid = report.person_id)";

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert1)) {
        die('Error inserting record');
    } //end of nested if statement

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert2)) {
        die('Error inserting record');
    } //end of nested if statement

    $newrecord = "new record added to database";
} //end of if statement

?>
```

I have created the variable `$pid` which will find the last `person_id` generated in the `person` table, I have tested this and it works in phpmyadmin. I want to then use this variable to link the date with the `person_id` and place it into the `report` table.

This may sound quite complicated but I'm sure there is an easy answer.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: AFAIK there is no `INSERT INTO...WHERE` statement in MySql. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with my lecturer and spending hours echoing out all the outcomes, we found that the connection sqli statement ('mysqli_query') was connecting to the server but wasn't actually connecting to the database itself, therefor not allowing the person_id to be pulled from the person table with the select statement.

We put in a standard sql connection statement and specified the database name separately. This now seems to work and I have added another foreign key from another table ('defect_id') and have added another insert statement for the defect table. I can now run this code and it works fine.

```
<?php

            if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('dbcon.php');

            //insert statement 1    
        $sqlinsert1 = "INSERT INTO person (title, first_name, last_name, address, contact_no, email, ha_id) VALUES ('$_POST[title]' , '$_POST[first_name]' , '$_POST[last_name]' , '$_POST[address]' , '$_POST[contact_no]' , '$_POST[email]' , '$_POST[ha_id]')";

        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert1)) {
        die('Error inserting record1');
        } //end of nested if statement1


                    // connect to database      
$dbcon2 = mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ); //mysqli query would not connect to db so using mysql connection

        if (!$dbcon2){
        die('error connecting to database');
        }

$dbselect = @mysql_select_db('potholes_v2');

        if (!$dbselect){
        die('error connecting database');
        }

                    //insert statement 2            
$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO defect (road, location, carriageway, lane, diameter, depth, speed, description) VALUES ('$_POST[road]' , '$_POST[location]' , '$_POST[carriageway]' , '$_POST[lane]' , '$_POST[diameter]' , '$_POST[depth]' , '$_POST[speed]' , '$_POST[description]')";

        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert2)) {
        die('Error inserting record2');
        } //end of nested if statement1


mysql_close(); //close database connection


                   //connect to database
$dbcon2 = mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ); //mysqli query would not connect to db so using mysql connection

        if (!$dbcon2){
        die('error connecting to host');
        }

$dbselect = @mysql_select_db('potholes_v2');

        if (!$dbselect){
        die('error connecting database');
        }

                    //select person_id value
$value = mysql_query("SELECT person_id FROM person ORDER BY person_id DESC" , $dbcon2); //selects last entry of person_id in person table

        if (!$value) {
        die ('error, no values'); //error if no value selected
        }

$value2 = mysql_result($value,0); //specifies new value to be inserted into report table as person_id foreign key

                    //select defect_id value    
$defect = mysql_query("SELECT defect_id FROM defect ORDER BY defect_id DESC" , $dbcon2); //selects last defect_id entry from defect table

        if (!$defect) {
        die ('Error, no values for defect'); //error if no value selected
        }

$defect2 = mysql_result($defect,0); //specifies new defect value to be placed in report table

                    //insert statement 3
$sqlinsert3 = "INSERT INTO report (date, person_id, defect_id) VALUES ('$_POST[date]' , $value2 , $defect2)"; //inserts date, person_id and defect_id values into report table

        if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert3)) {
        die('Error inserting record 3');
        } //end of nested if statement1


mysql_close(); //close database connection  





$newrecord = "new record added to database";  //gives feedback for successful submission

}  //end of initial if statement

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think error is in $_POST[date] using ' quotes. your code like following..

Take person id after when you are inserting a person.

and then insert in report

```
$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO report (report.pid,report.date) VALUES ('$pid',"$_POST['date']");//changed check it
```

then your both table will link together, with pid (reference key).

Comment: hmmm i tried this but it still errors on the second statement ($sqlinsert2)

Comment: check now i have made some changes in my answer.

Comment: no thats throwing up a syntax error unfortunately. I tried it with a few different quotes double and single in different places and it still errors on statement 2. I may have to go back to the drawing board with this.